# Json for loop Android

Tags: android, json, for-loop

hi friends sorry to disturb u but i am facing a problem when calling the for loop on the `Json` array where i can only display 2arrays but there are 3 array data i want to create the comment box just like the Facebook Comments i am struggling from 3days [this](http://sampletemplates.net/majority/api.php?action=getEvents&user_id=12&page=1&source=android) is my `Json` 
i also want to know how to use the arraylist on JSons and call using the index values of the array

[image: Images of Array]
[image: Images of Comments]
this is JAVACode

```
private void loadevent() {
        SharedPreferences eveid = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String eventid = eveid.getString("userid", "");
        String url = "http://sampletemplates.net/majority/api.php?action=getEvents&user_id=" + eventid + "&page=1&source=android";
        JsonArrayRequest eventreq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject evntobj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        CurrentList evtslsts = new CurrentList();
                        evtslsts.setEvid(evntobj.getInt("id"));
                        evtslsts.setEvtitle(evntobj.getString("title"));
                        evtslsts.setEvinfo(evntobj.getString("info"));
                        evtslsts.setEvimage(evntobj.getString("image"));
                        evtslsts.setEvvenue(evntobj.getString("venue"));
                        evtslsts.setEvtime_slot(evntobj.getString("time_slot"));
                        JSONArray cmtarray = evntobj.getJSONArray("comments");
                        for (int j = 0; j < cmtarray.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject c = cmtarray.getJSONObject(j);
//                            CurrentList commentsslsts = new CurrentList();
                            evtslsts.setEvtuserid(c.getInt("user_id"));
                            evtslsts.setEvtusername(c.getString("user_name"));
                            evtslsts.setEvcomment(c.getString("user_comment"));
                            evtslsts.setTimetaken(c.getString("time"));
//                            cmtslist.add(commentsslsts);
                        }
                        evntlist.add(evtslsts);
                    }
                    eventsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("res", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(eventreq);
    }
```

POJO CLass

```
public class CurrentList {
    private evtime_slot, evtusername, evcomment, timetaken;
    public CurrentList() {
    }
    public CurrentList(String evtusername, String timetaken, String evcomment) {
        this.evtuserid = evtuserid;
        this.evtusername = evtusername;
        this.timetaken = timetaken;
        this.evcomment = evcomment;
    }
    public String getEvcomment() {
        return evcomment;
    }
    public void setEvcomment(String evcomment) {
        this.evcomment = evcomment;
    }

    public String getEvtusername() {
        return evtusername;
    }

    public void setEvtusername(String evtusername) {
        this.evtusername = evtusername;
    }

    public String getTimetaken() {
        return timetaken;
    }

    public void setTimetaken(String timetaken) {
        this.timetaken = timetaken;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify exactly what you want to do or describe more about your question

Comment: Sir i had updated the details please once go through the Json and i want the comment box just like the facebook comment box sir

Answer (score 0):

In this case you cannot get all the comments in the json array because it is overwritten. Make comments as a array of objects or array list and set into the object evtslsts.then you can get it

Consider the following portion of code

```
JSONArray cmtarray = evntobj.getJSONArray("comments");
ArrayList<comment> comments=new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j < cmtarray.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject c = cmtarray.getJSONObject(j);
    comment com = new comment();
    com.setEvtuserid(c.getInt("user_id"));
    com.setEvtusername(c.getString("user_name"));
    com.setEvcomment(c.getString("user_comment"));
    com.setTimetaken(c.getString("time"));
    comments.add(commentsslsts);
}
evtslsts.setCooments(comments);
```

Here comment is a class having comment properties

Comment: comments is the getter and setter properties rightsir

Comment: comments is arraylist of comment class

Comment: sir i had updated the POjo class please once check it

Comment: this is ok CurrentList

Comment: i am getting spaces sir first 2 arrays

Comment: at first sir i will post the images sir